# Regular expression that match everything but two words

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
^(.*)$ https://mysite.com$1
```

It matches everything and then convert to:

```
anything.mysite.com/foo  --- >   mysite.com/foo
```

I will like to do something similar but only if the *anything word* is different from 2 specific words, I will like to execute that rewrite only if the sub-domain is different from string1 or string2. So:

```
string1.mysite.com/query     --->   https://string1.mysite.com/query
foo.mysite.com/query         --->   https://mysite.com/query
```

Comment: Are you using `mod_rewrite` here? If yes then can you show full rule?

Comment: @anubhava here's the most server oriented version of this question http://serverfault.com/questions/658422/manage-several-sub-domains-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Nginx here is what you can add in `server` block to disallow matching these 2 subdomains:

```
server_name ~^(?!string1|string2)[^.]+\.mysite\.com$;
```

`(?!string1|string2)` is **negative lookahead** that will match anything but `string1` or `string2`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with lookbehinds.
To remove the part you don't want, just replace with `$1$2`

```
 # ^(.*?(?://))?.*?(?<!\bstring1)(?<!\bstring2)\.(mysite\.com\b.*?)$

 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      .*? 
      (?: // )
 )?                            # (1 end)
 .*? 
 (?<! \b string1 )
 (?<! \b string2 )
 \.
 (                             # (2 start)
      mysite\.com \b 
      .*? 
 )                             # (2 end)
 $
```